# how to make visible a certain item on a navigation bar to a certain group of users?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Could anybody please tell me how to make visible a certain item on a navigation bar to a certain group of users?
For example I need an item 'Faculty' to be visible just for a certain group and the bar should look like this:

```
                                                 Home | Faculty | Student | Admin
```

and for all others it should be:

```
                                                           Home | Student | Admin
```

I would like to make it in one line, as somewhat similar to this:

```
 {% if user.groups.filter(name='Faculty group').exists() %}
      <li>Faculty</li>
 {% endif %}
```

but there is a mistake in this implementation. 
Thank you very much for suggestions!

Comment: Well, the mistake is that that is invalid syntax in templates; you can't call functions with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to make a proprety in your user model :

```
@property
def is_faculty(self):
    return self.groups.filter(name='Faculty group').exists()
```

and now change your template like that :

```
{% if user.is_faculty %}
      <li>Faculty</li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if request.user.groups.all.0.name == 'the group name' %}
      <li>Faculty</li>
 {% endif %}
```

try this

Comment: Thank you very much! That's an elegant one